# CodeIgniter Module System

Tags: php, codeigniter

If this question is already asked, I apologize, but couldn't find anything that could solve this. I have a project on CodeIgniter and I want to create a module/plugin/extension system, just like Joomla or any other CMS where you can add custom built modules with different functionality, but haven't done anything like this before, so I'm asking for a way of making this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module system for codeigniter HMVC

Go to https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Download branches **default download for codeigniter 2 HMVC** and you can download **codeigniter 3 HMVC latest version for CI-3**

That way you can create your own modules how ever you want. I am making something like open cart but for codeigniter.